# QHBoxLayout Spacing

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlayout

I have an `QHBoxLayout` that includes two `QLabel` widgets. My left `QLabel` is much larger than my right `QLabel`, however, the `QHBoxLayout` is splitting the output in half, so the left side of the layout is too small and the right side of the layout is too big. How do I modify the `QHBoxLayout` to create unequal proportioned space for each included widget?

Answer (score 8):

The layout system should reserve more space for the larger label, if it needs it, and if there is space available.

If you want to force the layout to reserve specific amount of space for the larger label, you can use [`QBoxLayout::setStretch`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#setStretch).

For example, if you want to reserve 70% of the space for the larger label, and 30% for the smaller one, you can use this:

```
ui->horizontalLayout->setStretch(0, 7);
ui->horizontalLayout->setStretch(1, 3);
```

Or, you can make the smaller label only reserve the absolute minimum space it needs, and the larger label to reserve as much space as it can by using size policies.

For the smaller label, set the horizontal size policy to `QSizePolicy::Maximum`, and for the larger label, set the horizontal size policy to `QSizePolicy::Minimum` (or `QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding`).

```
ui->label_Large->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
ui->label_Small->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
```

You can see what different size policies do [*here*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum).